# Let Canon EOS M6 prefer <1/100 exposure time with slightly higher ISO?

Tags: canon, motion-blur, auto-iso

I frequently get motion blur with my Canon EOS M6. I noticed that the camera usually automatically choose very low ISO and a slow shutter:

Example EXIF:   18mm  f/3.5  1/80 sec  ISO 100  (mode was aperture priority: f/3.5)

I assume ISO 400 won't make much a difference on the image quality, and the exposure time can be 1/320 sec, eliminating common motion blur from human motion.

I can achieve by using manual mode, but it's quite inconvenient. Is there a way to let the camera know I prefer slightly higher ISO compared with >1/100 sec shutter? Is there major considerations not doing this?

Comment: Yes, you can do this. I checked your [camera manual](https://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/8/0300026878/02/EOS_M6_User_Guide_EN.pdf). No need for Manual mode if you don't want to use it. Do you have some trouble setting ISO to 400?

Comment: Just to confirm: You have an original M6 and not an M6 Mark II?

Comment: I have original m6.

Comment: If I set ISO to 400, then in darker environment I have to adjust it to a higher value. I wish better automation

Comment: Have you tried Program Exposure mode with Safety Shift (set to ISO, rather than Tv/Av) and Auto ISO enabled? In P mode you can always shift with the main dial, you just have to pay attention to the Tv displayed in the viewfinder.

Answer (score 3):

Aperture priority is just the wrong mode for you to be in.

Aperture priority is for when shutter speed does not matter. It tells the camera to choose a shutter speed by itself.

What you want is either shutter priority (if aperture does not matter) or manual mode (if it does), possibly with automatic ISO which I believe Canon mirrorless cameras all support.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the camera to shutter priority mode, which is Tv on the mode dial.  You can then set the shutter speed you want and the camera will choose the aperture and the ISO to get what it thinks is a proper exposure.

On my M6 Mk II the ISO setting is not available when in full auto mode.  If you change the mode to P you can set the ISO to what you want.  The camera will still choose aperture and shutter speed for you.

The scene mode has a sports setting.  I believe that will prioritize a faster shutter but have not tried it.

Comment: The M6 Mark II also allows one to select a minimum Tv (it's actually a maximum - but too many folks think 1/500 is "less" than 1/1000 when the reverse is true) when in Av exposure mode. Thus one can select the Av they want, set the minimum Tv, select Auto ISO, and disable safety shift with the M6 Mark II. This allows for rapidly changing brightness, such as from indoors to outdoors, or from heavy shade to direct sunlight. Using Tv unnecessarily restricts the Tv to a single value when a shorter one might be acceptable. But the M6 does not have the minimum Tv setting when in P or Av mode.

Comment: Thanks. I think minimum Tv would be the answer then. This sounds a software feature, but they maybe they won't bring it to the old M6 yo make me upgrade:(

Comment: It's not _just_ to make you upgrade. There is not a conspiracy behind every decision. It just doesn't make business sense to continually add retrospective features to old products. Businesses weigh up costs versus benefit, and the resources/costs needed to develop firmware for old cameras would be better applied to areas that bring (new) revenue into the company. Software engineers, project managers, testers, etc don't work for free, and companies need to secure their own future. So maybe yes, it is to make you upgrade.

Comment: Agreed. But it’s also how smart phones gaining popularity for photography over the time: better software support and programmability.